# Explanation of the thinness ratio formula?

Tags: geometry

I am looking for sliver polygons (term used in geographic information systems for long thin 2D surfaces) and am using the following formula to identify which polygons have a smaller area to circumference ratio (a.k.a. the thinness ratio):
$$
  \frac{4 \cdot \pi \cdot \text{area}}{\text{perimeter}^2}
$$
That much I understand. But what is not fully clear, is the $4 \cdot \pi$ bit and why the length has to be squared. Can someone explain this in simple terms?

Comment: 1) The length are squared so that the ratio is invariant under scaling. 2) The $4\pi$ is a normalization factor to set the ratio to $1$ for a circle. In fact, by isoperimetric inequality, all shapes has ratio $\le 1$ and $= 1$ when and only when the shape is a circle.

Comment: This has been cross-posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/151939

Answer (score 4):

The reasoning behind the **Thinness ratio** is that we compare the **measured area** with the theoretical area of a circle with the same **perimeter** (circumference). If they are similar their ratio will approach to one.

$$ Th = \frac{A_{measured}}{A_{theoretical}}\tag{1}$$

So the first question we have to ask is, **what's the theoretical area of a circle with the same perimeter?**
The circle area is: $$A_{theoretical}=\pi\times r^{2}   \tag{2}$$

But we don't have the **radius** however we know that the circumference (aka perimeter) is equal to:
$$ (p)erimeter =  2\pi\times r$$
Hence:
$$ r = \frac{p}{2\pi}$$
Substututing in equation 2:
$$A_{theoretical}=\pi\times (\frac{p}{2\pi})^{2} = \frac{p^{2}}{4 \pi}$$
Finnaly substituting in 1:
$$ Th = \frac{4\pi \times A_{measured}}{p^{2}}$$